# Is there a good way to cross-compile SFML for windows from a Linux install

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sfml, mingw-w64

So I have been making an application in SFML and my friend wanted to try it out on his windows machine(he's not too tech savy so he couldn't compile it himself, though not for lack of trying).  I figured that I'd just compile my program with MinGW and send him an executable, problem is, when I try to run the application I get the following message:

```
009c:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
00ec:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-graphics-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00ec:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-system-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00ec:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-window-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00ec:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00ec:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00ec:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

So Ignoring the first error I can see that the program wants dll files to be attached to it.  Problem is I don't know how to do that and this is where I have run into hurdles for every way I've tried to compile this thing.  I've tried to link the dlls as libraries (for which I switched to cmake, cause even though I don't like using it, I wouldn't have to type a memoir into the terminal).  I have what seems to be a decent windows toolchain from the web but when I tried to link the dll files with:

```
target_link_libraries (SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/openal32.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-audio-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-graphics-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-network-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-system-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-window-2.dll)
```

This gives a different error of:

```
MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=windows.cmake CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target
  "SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/openal32.dll"
  which is not built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kyle/Documents/tileMapEditor/Windows/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I'm sorry if this in in any way incoherent or is lacking information.  I've been working on compiling this for a week and have tried installing windows and compiling it there. (That sucked!  I hate GUIs as options move and it takes forever to find out where they moved) I went back to CMake but I don't ever use CMake as I just use raw g++, so I wound up using CMake off of various online posts (CMake's guide sucks btw).

To Clarify the question is if there is a decent way to compile this.  I will use CMake or the command line, I just need to get it to compile for windows and run in wine.

=========================================================================

UPDATE: I've tried to copy the dll files over to the project folder but that was not the end of my problems.  I rebuilt the game and I now get this huge list of errors:

```
008c:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-system-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-graphics-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-system-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-window-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-window-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-window-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-window-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-graphics-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-graphics-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-graphics-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-graphics-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-system-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-system-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-window-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-window-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\sfml-window-2.dll") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library sfml-window-2.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00f0:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe") not found
00f0:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\kyle\\Documents\\tileMapEditor\\Windows\\build\\TOSTE.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Is there something big I'm missing here?  My CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(TOSTE)

add_executable(TOSTE Main.cpp userInterface.cpp userInterface.hpp tileRenderer.cpp tileRenderer.hpp Button.cpp Button.hpp)

target_link_libraries (TOSTE sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
target_link_libraries (SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/openal32.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-audio-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-graphics-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-network-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-system-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-window-2.dll
```

The tool chain I am using contains the following:

```
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
    set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

    # cross compilers to use for C, C++ and Fortran
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
    set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gfortran)
    set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

    # target environment on the build host system
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

    # modify default behavior of FIND_XXX() commands
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

I am really hoping there is a better way of doing this, as it is really gross.  I'm also tempted to just use a compatibility tool to run the app on windows as the version I have now should work for MacOS and Linux.

Comment: Attaching dlls is easy, you just place them in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: I've added the dlls to my project folder but I just get more errors I've reflected this in the original post

Answer (score 2):

Windows expects DLL files to be placed either in the PATH directory or in the same directory as the executable.
If you want your DLLs to be placed in a different directory, you should add it to the PATH. When running your program with Wine, you can do that by setting the variable `WINEPATH`:

> WINEPATH=/path/to/dlls ./TOSTE.exe

#### Building with CMake

You are calling `target_link_libraries` wrong. As the name suggests, it expects a CMake target as the first arguments. So instead of

```
target_link_libraries (SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/openal32.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-audio-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-graphics-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-network-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-system-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-window-2.dll)
```

you should do

```
target_link_libraries (MY_PROGRAM_TARGET SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/openal32.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-audio-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-graphics-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-network-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-system-2.dll SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/sfml-window-2.dll)
```

You can also make it shorter by supplying the link_directory, which is

> "SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/"

in your case.

```
target_link_directories(MY_PROGRAM_TARGET PRIVATE SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/bin/)
target_link_libraries(MY_PROGRAM_TARGET openal32 sfml-audio sfml-graphics sfml-network sfml-system sfml-window)
```

If you want all the linked DLLs to be copied to your executable's directory, you can use the [`TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS) generator expression added to CMake 3.21.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MY_PROGRAM_TARGET POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:MY_PROGRAM_TARGET> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MY_PROGRAM_TARGET>
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
  )
```

It only supports Windows DLLs at the moment.